# SOCKET Handling Concurrent server and client comunication

Tags: java, sockets

I'm experiencing some problems with sockets.

I'm trying to make a concurrent server to accept more than one clients.

When a client connects to the server, the server creates a new thread and listens to the socket. 
Then, if the client sends something, the server must read it.

On the client i just open a dictionary (txt form) and i send it over the socket.

On the server the only thing i get is this:

#

null

SERVER

```
    try
             {
                String message,file = new String("StressTextFile.txt");
                File filee = new File(file);
                long length;

                 // Open the file 
                 FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
                 // Get the object of DataInputStream
                 DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                 String strLine = new String();

                 length  = filee.length();

                 ProgressBar.setMaximum((int)length); //we're going to get this many bytes
                 ProgressBar.setValue(0); //we've gotten 0 bytes so far
                  //Read File Line By Line

                font1 = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18);
                font1.isBold();
                color = new Color( 74,118,110);
                TextArea1.setForeground(color);
                TextArea1.setFont(font1);

                 int soma=0;
                    while(in.readLine() != null)
                    {
                        strLine = in.readLine();  // reads from file
                        //System.out.println(strLine);


                        TextArea1.append(strLine+"\n");

                        pwOut.write(strLine);
                        pwOut.flush();

                        soma+=strLine.length()+1;
                        ProgressBar.setValue(ProgressBar.getValue()+(strLine.length()+1)*2);
                        ProgressBar.repaint();              
                    };

                    br.close();
                    pwOut.close();
                    Skt.close();
            }catch (Exception e){  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());  }
          }
```

CLIENT

```
    try
    {

        brIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));


        while(s != null)
        {

            s = brIn.readLine();
            System.out.println("#####");
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    } 
    catch (IOException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();    }
```

Please forget the Swing components.
I think all socket stuff are ok. why can't i get nothing on the server side?

Please help

Kind regards

Comment: It seems to me you did not post the relevant code. There is just one line working on a server socket (`Skt.close();`) - assuming that `Skt` is the ServerSocket. Please provide a meaningful example...

Comment: Sorry my mistake. The server code is the shorter one and the Client code is the one tagged as Server..

What in specifically do you want me to provide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A barebones example of a multi-threaded server:

```
//MyServer.java
public class MyServer {

  private static int PORT = 12345;

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    while(true) new MyServerThread(s.accept());

  }
```

And your server thread:

```
//MyServerThread.java
public class MyServerThread implements Runnable {

  private InputStream in = null;
  private OutputStream out = null;

  public MyServerThread(Socket s) {

    in = s.getInputStream();
    out = s.getOutputStream();

    (new Thread(this)).start();
  }

  public void run() {
    //do stuff with **in** and **out** to interact with client
  }
}
```

Missing from this example:

- Error handling
- `close()`ing the sockets/streams
- shutting down the server
- the clientside

Hopefully that gives you some idea of how it usually looks.

Comment: Yeah i miss the while true.. but I think the rest is ok.. i guess

Answer (score 0):

OK so the Server is something like this:

public class KnockKnockServer 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
        {

```
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        RunnableThread rt;

        try { serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4443);} 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4443.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try 
        { 

            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            rt = new RunnableThread("t1",clientSocket);
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        serverSocket.close();
    }
}


        class RunnableThread implements Runnable 
{

    Thread runner;
    Socket skt;

    public RunnableThread(String threadName,Socket cliSock) 
    {
        runner = new Thread(this, threadName); // (1) Create a new thread.


        skt = cliSock;
        runner.run();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void run() 
    {

        //Display info about this particular thread
        //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());

        //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader brIn;
        String s = new String();


        try
        {

            brIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));


            while(s != null)
            {

                s = brIn.readLine();
                System.out.println("#####");
                System.out.println(s);
            }

        } 
        catch (IOException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();    }

    }
}
```

In the Client the only thing that interacts with the server is when i read the words from the dictionary file (StressTextFile.txt) and send it over the Socket:

```
public void SendToServer()
    {

        new Thread() 
            {
              public void run() 
              {
                try
                 {
                    String message,file = new String("StressTextFile.txt");
                    File filee = new File(file);
                    long length;

                     // Open the file 
                     FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
                     // Get the object of DataInputStream
                     DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                     String strLine = new String();

                     length  = filee.length();

                     ProgressBar.setMaximum((int)length); //we're going to get this many bytes
                     ProgressBar.setValue(0); //we've gotten 0 bytes so far
                      //Read File Line By Line

                    font1 = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18);
                    font1.isBold();
                    color = new Color( 74,118,110);
                    TextArea1.setForeground(color);
                    TextArea1.setFont(font1);

                     int soma=0;
                        while(in.readLine() != null)
                        {
                            strLine = in.readLine();  // reads from file
                            //System.out.println(strLine);


                            TextArea1.append(strLine+"\n");

                            pwOut.write(strLine);
                            pwOut.flush();

                            soma+=strLine.length()+1;
                            ProgressBar.setValue(ProgressBar.getValue()+(strLine.length()+1)*2);
                            ProgressBar.repaint();              
                        };

                        br.close();
                        pwOut.close();
                        Skt.close();
                }catch (Exception e){  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());  }
              }
            }.start();
    }
```

***FOR DOCUMENTATION:***

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;


public class Graphics extends JFrame  implements ActionListener 
{

    private JPanel Panel;
    public JLabel LabelConnect;
    public JLabel DataSent;
    public JLabel DataReceived;
    private JTextField TextFieldOutPUT;
    private JButton ConnectButton;
    private JButton Sendinformation;
    private int value;
    private JTextArea TextArea1; 
    private JTextArea TextArea2; 
    private JProgressBar ProgressBar;
    private Socket Skt;
    private PrintWriter pwOut;
    private boolean CONNECTED;
    private Border border;
    private Color color;
    private Font font1;
    private JScrollPane ScrollBar1;
    private JScrollPane ScrollBar2;

    public Graphics() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {


        value = 0;

        Panel = new JPanel();

        font1 = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 15);
        font1.isBold();

        LabelConnect = new JLabel();
        DataReceived = new JLabel();
        DataSent = new JLabel();
        TextFieldOutPUT = new JTextField();
        ConnectButton = new JButton("Connect");
        TextArea1 = new JTextArea("ola");
        TextArea2 = new JTextArea("Adeus");
        Sendinformation = new JButton("Send");
        ProgressBar = new JProgressBar();

        Sendinformation.setLayout(null);
        Sendinformation.setBounds(340, 450, 100, 25);
        Sendinformation.setVisible(true);
        Sendinformation.addActionListener(this);


        color = new Color( 211,211,211);

        TextArea1.setVisible(true);
        TextArea1.setLayout(null);
        TextArea2.setVisible(true);
        TextArea2.setLayout(null);

        ScrollBar1 = new JScrollPane(TextArea1);
        ScrollBar1.setLayout(null);
        ScrollBar1.setVisible(true);
        ScrollBar1.setBounds(210,40,15,400);
        ScrollBar1.setEnabled(true);
        ScrollBar1.setVisible(true);
        ScrollBar1.setBackground(color);
        ScrollBar1.setBounds(10,40,210,400);

        ScrollBar2 = new JScrollPane(TextArea2);
        ScrollBar2.setLayout(null);
        ScrollBar2.setVisible(true);
        ScrollBar2.setEnabled(true);
        ScrollBar2.setBackground(color);
        ScrollBar2.setBounds(230,40,210,400);
        ScrollBar2.setLayout(null);
        ScrollBar2.setVisible(true);




        border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Reading...");


        ProgressBar.setLayout(null);
        ProgressBar.setBounds(10,450,320,25);
        ProgressBar.setValue(0);
        ProgressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        //ProgressBar.setBorderPainted(border);
        ProgressBar.setVisible(true);




        TextFieldOutPUT.setVisible(true);
        TextFieldOutPUT.setBounds(10,500,320,25);

        ConnectButton.addActionListener(this);
        ConnectButton.setLayout(null);
        ConnectButton.setVisible(true);
        ConnectButton.setBounds(340, 500, 100, 25);

        LabelConnect.setBounds(10,478,320,25);
        LabelConnect.setVisible(true);
        LabelConnect.setFont(font1);
        LabelConnect.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        LabelConnect.setText("Connect");

        font1 = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18);


        DataReceived.setBounds(235,10,200,25);
        DataReceived.setVisible(true);
        DataReceived.setFont(font1);
        DataReceived.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        DataReceived.setText("Data Received");

        DataSent.setBounds(15,10,200,25);
        DataSent.setVisible(true);
        DataSent.setFont(font1);
        DataSent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        DataSent.setText("Data Sent");



        color = new Color(108,166,205);
        Panel.setBackground(color);


        Panel.add(ScrollBar1);
        Panel.add(ScrollBar2);
        Panel.add(DataSent);
        Panel.add(DataReceived);
        Panel.add(Sendinformation);
        Panel.add(ProgressBar);
        Panel.add(ConnectButton);
        Panel.add(TextFieldOutPUT);
        Panel.add(LabelConnect);
        Panel.setVisible(true);
        Panel.setLayout(null);
        Panel.setBounds(500,400,800,600);


        add(Panel);
        this.setSize(459,560 );

        setVisible(true);
    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

        //Object obj = new obj(e.get)

        if(e.getSource() == ConnectButton)
        {
            if(!CONNECTED)
            {
                String s = new String(TextFieldOutPUT.getText());

                try {Skt = new Socket(s, 4443); Skt.close();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e2) {e2.printStackTrace(); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Panel, "Connection could not be established!!"); return;
                } catch (IOException e2) {e2.printStackTrace(); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Panel, "Connection could not be established!!");return;}  



                System.out.println(s);

                try {ConnectCLIENT(s);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
            }
            else
            {
                try {   Skt.close();  } catch (IOException e1){  e1.printStackTrace();  }
                ConnectButton.setText("Connect");
                TextFieldOutPUT.setEditable(true);
                CONNECTED = false;
                Panel.repaint();

            }

        }

        if(e.getSource() == Sendinformation){ 

            System.out.print("Sendinformation");
            if(CONNECTED)
                SendToServer(); 
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Panel, "You are not connecte to the server!! Please connect!!");

        }

    }

    public void ConnectCLIENT(String socketStr) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {


        try{
            Skt = new Socket(socketStr, 4443);
            pwOut = new PrintWriter(Skt.getOutputStream(),true);
            System.out.print("Connected");
            TextFieldOutPUT.setEditable(false);
            ConnectButton.setText("Disconnect");
            CONNECTED = true;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Panel, "Connection Sucessfully established!!");
            Panel.repaint();
            }
        catch(Exception E){E.printStackTrace();}

    }

    public void SendToServer()
    {

        new Thread() 
            {
              public void run() 
              {
                try
                 {
                    String message,file = new String("StressTextFile.txt");
                    File filee = new File(file);
                    long length;

                     // Open the file 
                     FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
                     // Get the object of DataInputStream
                     DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                     String strLine = new String();

                     length  = filee.length();

                     ProgressBar.setMaximum((int)length); //we're going to get this many bytes
                     ProgressBar.setValue(0); //we've gotten 0 bytes so far
                      //Read File Line By Line

                    font1 = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18);
                    font1.isBold();
                    color = new Color( 74,118,110);
                    TextArea1.setForeground(color);
                    TextArea1.setFont(font1);

                     int soma=0;
                        while(in.readLine() != null)
                        {
                            strLine = in.readLine();  // reads from file
                            //System.out.println(strLine);


                            TextArea1.append(strLine+"\n");

                            pwOut.write(strLine);
                            pwOut.flush();

                            soma+=strLine.length()+1;
                            ProgressBar.setValue(ProgressBar.getValue()+(strLine.length()+1)*2);
                            ProgressBar.repaint();              
                        };

                        br.close();
                        pwOut.close();
                        Skt.close();
                }catch (Exception e){  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());  }
              }
            }.start();
    }

}
```