# How to accept more than one connections with Android BluetoothServerSocket?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am making an Android App in which one Server has to share data with multiple Clients and one Client accesses data from multiple Servers. The problem is that Client can connect to multiple Servers using connect() but Server won't accept() for more than one connection at a time. I have read through Bluetooth page at developers.android and picked up the following from there

> Unlike TCP/IP, RFCOMM only allows one connected client per channel at a time, so in most cases it makes sense to call close() on the BluetoothServerSocket immediately after accepting a connected socket.

So is there way to accept multiple clients on BluetoothServerSocket or establish multiple RFCOMMs from the Server side or some work around this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think i faced a similar problem and tried making separate ServerSocket for each connection that i wanted to accept by using separate UUIDs for each connection. I guess that made each ServerSocket listen on different RFCOMM channels.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, there's no need to create multiple `BluetoothServerSocket`s with different UUIDs. Whenever a connection is established, have another thread handle the `socket.getOutputStream()`, but keep accepting/listening using the same `BluetoothServerSocket` in the main thread.

On the android reference page [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothServerSocket.html#accept()):

> accept () blocks until a connection is established. Returns a connected BluetoothSocket on successful connection.
>
> Once this call returns, it can be called again to accept subsequent
>   incoming connections.

I found a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12940318/2073825).

Comment: Doesn't each UUID have only one channel? Thus, if only client is accepted per channel you need a different UUID per client? Also, the "good example" you found seems to deal with "regular" TCP/IP sockets which don't work the same way as Bluetooth sockets. Those allow multiple clients per channel as said in the Android docs: "Unlike TCP/IP, RFCOMM only allows one connected client per channel at a time(...)"